# Parse and Swift Geopoints not saving

Tags: swift, parse-platform, geopoints

I have tried everything. No matter what my Geopoints will not save when using an actual device with xcode or using the simulator.

```
if signUpError == nil {
   PFGeoPoint.geoPointForCurrentLocationInBackground {
   (geoPoint: PFGeoPoint?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
     if error == nil {
        PFUser.currentUser()!.setValue(geoPoint, forKey: "location")
      }
}
```

I am not sure what to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because you are setting it but you are not saving the value you just set:

```
if signUpError == nil {
   PFGeoPoint.geoPointForCurrentLocationInBackground {
   (geoPoint: PFGeoPoint?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
     if error == nil {
        PFUser.currentUser()!.setValue(geoPoint, forKey: "location")
        PFUser.currentUser().saveInBackground() 
      }
}
```

Comment: I am so glad that you saved me from that much stress over something so small

Comment: @user2967062 We have all been there, glad I could help. Good luck finish your app!